# Package is not visible error

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I was trying to use joptsimple package in my project but I get following error:

```
Error:(4, 20) java: package jdk.internal.joptsimple is not visible
  (package jdk.internal.joptsimple is declared in module jdk.internal.opt, which does not export it to the unnamed module)
```

Any ideas what should I do with it?

Comment: Does it mean there is no way i can import this package?

Comment: if this package is not exported in the module you are using, then you can't use this package.

Comment: Do you have JOpt Simple on your class path? I wonder if this is just your IDE suggesting you import jdk.internal.joptsimple.OptionParser rather than joptsimple.OptionParser? If so, that would be an IDE bug as it should never automatically import a non-exported package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the message clearly reads (in fact notice the beautiful naming convention by JDK devs "**internal**" meaning they don't want to expose them) that the API you're trying to access is in a package that is not exported to any other module except these  -

```
exports jdk.internal.joptsimple to jdk.jlink, jdk.jshell
```

even if you add `requires jdk.internal.opt` module in your declaration.

---

To make use of classes from these packages should be avoided.

**Also since even the [Open JDK itself integrates JOpt Simple for internal usage by JDK tools.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8148154)**  I would suggest you make use of the library **[`jopt-simple`](http://jopt-simple.github.io/jopt-simple/)** for a long-term solution by adding the dependency on your modulepath(java9) or classpath(java8) using -

Maven -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
    <version>6.0-alpha-2</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:-

```
compile 'net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:6.0-alpha-2'
```

After the inclusion of which the package name in use in your classes shall simply be **`joptsimple.*`** instead of <strike>`jdk.internal.joptsimple.*`</strike>.

Answer (score 7):

You are apparently using an internal API, which you shouldn't. Such APIs are not standardized - they can differ from JVM to JVM and may change at any time without notice.

That said, if you still want to use it, you can do so by adding the following command line flag at compile and run time (i.e. to `javac` and `java`):

```
--add-exports jdk.internal.opt/jdk.internal.joptsimple=ALL-UNNAMED
```

If you are creating a module you must replace `ALL-UNNAMED` by your module name.

Comment: If you are creating a module you MUST replace ALL-UNNAMED by your module name, or else it won't work.

Comment: Absolutely, @MichaelBöckling, I just fixed the phrasing. Thanks for pointing it out.