# IntelliJ is unable to detect jdk.crypto.cryptoki package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11, pkcs#11

I'm trying to use `jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11` in IntelliJ, but for some reason it keeps throwing errors. It seems like it's unable to detect this package. One of the solutions was to add `--add-exports jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper=ALL-UNNAMED` in the settings, which I did, but now it throws a compile time error in the IDE:

```
Error:(5, 20) java: package sun.security.pkcs11 is not visible
  (package sun.security.pkcs11 is declared in module jdk.crypto.cryptoki, which is not in the module graph)
```

I'm using Java 11. It works fine when I try to compile and run it over the terminal

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried restarting & invalidating caches?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120439/package-is-not-visible-error

Comment: Yep, multiple times :) @DanielScarfe