# Maven package is not visible compile error

Tags: java, maven, jar, package

I am using maven within VS Code and am getting a compile error from a jar I loaded from the mvn central repository.

`package com.fazecast.jSerialComm is not visible`

The import is declared as:

`import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;`

The pom.xml has:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fazecast</groupId>
    <artifactId>jSerialComm</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The jar is at `C:\Users\ray\.m2\repository\com\fazecast\jSerialComm\2.9.1\jSerialComm-2.9.1.jar`

What simple bone headed thing am I missing here? Thanks!

Edit:
The module.info content is as follows:

```
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    
    opens com.mystuff to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.mystuff;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package is not visible error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120439/package-is-not-visible-error)

Comment: Is your project using the module-system (does it have a module-info.java)?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam thanks, I did see that question during my searching but this isn't an internal access problem. I have compiled and run this program using VS Code "open folder" where it just compiles classes into .java files and runs.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the response, I've added the module-info.java contents above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tripped across the solution. My module-info.java needed an additional requires added to it:

```
module com.mystuff{
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires com.fazecast.jSerialComm;

    opens com.mystuffto javafx.fxml;
    exports com.mystuff;
}
```